# in Scilab matrices' Plot color

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i am a newbie to SciLab and I am  trying to plot a result of the matrix on a solution to the ODE . I am getting a little bit confused about minor issue , how do you differentiate the color of the plots ?

i have tried to give x(1) to ( 3 ) the color of plots , but the comp iler  gives an error message of incompatible   size of the  matrix .

Any idea on how to sol,ve this ? 
Thank u very much fotr the explanation  !

Here the code I copy from MATHEMATICS :

```
//trp operon conc nach Sinha , negative regulation 
delta_M=0.48
 delta_Y=0.03
 delta_L=0.02
 delta_P=0.04
a1=0.29
 a2=0.01
 a3=0.01
 K2=2920000
 K1=K2/100
 RT=23.2
 c1=18.8
 d1=10
kL=60000
 KML=680
 kg=3600
 KMg=700000
 mu=0.7
 t_M=0.2
g= 4


A=[-a1 0 1/RT-1/(RT)^2 ; c1 -a2 0; g^0.5 d1-delta_P a3]
function xdot=f(t, x)
    xdot=A*x
endfunction
x0=[0.1 0.1 0.1 ]';
t0=0;
t=0:0.1:2;
x = ode(x0,t0,t,f);
plot(t,x(1),'r-',t,x(2),'b-x',t,x(3),'y-d')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have more success if you give the correct slice of the array to plot.

Use

```
plot(t,x(1,:)),'r-',t,x(2,:),'b-x',t,x(3,:),'y-d')
```